# Nesting of subexpressions in expression templates

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp, perfect-forwarding, expression-templates

We are writing an expression template library to handle operations on values with a sparse gradient vector (first order automatic differentiation). I am trying to figure out how to make it possible to nest sub-expressions by reference or values depending on whether the expressions are temporaries or not.

We have a class Scalar which is containing a value and a sparse gradient vector. We use expression templates (like Eigen) to prevent the construction and allocation of too many temporaries `Scalar` objects. Thus we have the class `Scalar` inheriting from `ScalarBase<Scalar>` (CRTP).

A binary operation (eg +, *) between objects of type `ScalarBase< Left >` and `ScalarBase< Right >` return a `ScalarBinaryOp<Left, Right,BinaryOp>` object which inherits from `ScalarBase< ScalarBinaryOp<Left, Right,BinaryOp> >`:

```cpp
template< typename Left, typename Right >
ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, BinaryAdditionOp > operator+(
    const ScalarBase< Left >& left, const ScalarBase< Right >& right )
{
    return ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, BinaryAdditionOp >( static_cast< const Left& >( left ),
        static_cast< const Right& >( right ), BinaryAdditionOp{} );
}
```

`ScalarBinaryOp` must hold a value or reference to the operands objects of type `Left` and `Right`. The type of the holder is defined by template specialization of `RefTypeSelector< Expression >::Type`.

Currently this is always a const reference. It works at the moment for our test cases but this does not seem correct or safe to hold a reference to temporary subexpressions.

Obviously we also do not want that a `Scalar` object containing the sparse gradient vector be copied. If `x` and `y` are `Scalar`, the expression `x+y` should hold const reference to `x` and `y`. However if `f` is a function from `Scalar` to `Scalar`, `x+f(y)` should hold a const reference to `x` and the value of `f(y)`.

Hence I would like to pass the information about whether subexpressions are temporaries or not. I can add this to the expression type parameters:

`ScalarBinaryOp< typename Left, typename Right, typename BinaryOp , bool LeftIsTemporary, bool RightIsTemporary >`

and to the `RefTypeSelector`:

`RefTypeSelector< Expression, ExpressionIsTemporary  >::Type`

But then I would need to define for every binary operators 4 methods:

```
ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, BinaryAdditionOp, false, false > operator+(
    const ScalarBase< Left >& left, const ScalarBase< Right >& right );
ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, BinaryAdditionOp, false, true > operator+(
    const ScalarBase< Left >& left, ScalarBase< Right >&& right );
ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, BinaryAdditionOp, true, false > operator+(
    ScalarBase< Left >&& left, const ScalarBase< Right >& right );
ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, BinaryAdditionOp, true, true > operator+(
    ScalarBase< Left >&& left, ScalarBase< Right >&& right )
```

I would prefer to be able to achieve this with perfect forwarding. However I do not know how I can achieve this here. First I cannot use simple "universal references" because they match almost anything. I guess it might be possible to combine universal references and SFINAE to only allow certain parameter types but I am not sure this is the way to go. Also I would like to know if I could encode the information about whether Left and Right were originally lvalue or rvalue references in the types Left and Right which parameterize the `ScalarBinaryOp` instead of using the 2 additional booleans parameter and how to retrieve that information.

I have to support gcc 4.8.5 which is mostly c++11 compliant.

**update 2019/08/15: implementation**

```cpp
template < typename Expr >
class RefTypeSelector
{
   private:
   using Expr1 = typename std::decay<Expr>::type;
   public:
   using Type = typename std::conditional<std::is_lvalue_reference<Expr>::value, const Expr1&,Expr1>::type;
};
```

```cpp
template< typename Left, typename Right, typename Op >
class ScalarBinaryOp : public ScalarBase< ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, Op > >
{

public:

    template <typename L, typename R>
    ScalarBinaryOp( L&& left, R&& right, const Op& op )
        : left_( std::forward<L>(left) )
        , right_( std::forward<R>(right) ))
        , ...
    {
    ...
    }

    ...

private:
    /** LHS expression */
    typename RefTypeSelector< Left >::Type left_;

    /** RHS expression */
    typename RefTypeSelector< Right >::Type right_;

...
}
```

```cpp
template< typename Left, typename Right,
typename Left1 = typename std::decay<Left>::type,
typename Right1 = typename std::decay<Right>::type,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ScalarBase<Left1>, Left1>::value,int>::type = 0,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ScalarBase<Right1>, Right1>::value,int>::type = 0 >
ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, BinaryAdditionOp > operator+(
    Left&& left, Right&& right )
{

    return ScalarBinaryOp< Left, Right, BinaryAdditionOp >( std::forward<Left>( left ),
        std::forward<Right>( right ), BinaryAdditionOp{} );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode lvalue/rvalue information into `Left` and `Right` types. For example:

```
ScalarBinaryOp<Left&&, Right&&> operator+(
    ScalarBase<Left>&& left, ScalarBase<Right>&& right)
{
    return ...;
}
```

with `ScalarBinaryOp` being something like this:

```
template<class L, class R>
struct ScalarBinaryOp
{
    using Left = std::remove_reference_t<L>;
    using Right = std::remove_reference_t<R>;

    using My_left = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_rvalue_reference_v<L>, Left, const Left&>;
    using My_right = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_rvalue_reference_v<R>, Left, const Right&>;

    ...

    My_left left_;
    My_right right_;
};
```

---

Alternatively, you can be explicit and store everything by value, except for `Scalar`s. To be able to store a `Scalar` by value, you use a wrapper class:

```
x + Value_wrapper(f(y))
```

The wrapper is simple:

```
struct Value_wrapper : Base<Value_wrapper> {
    Value_wrapper(Scalar&& scalar) : scalar_(std::move(scalar)) {}

    operator Scalar() const {
        return std::move(scalar_);
    }

    Scalar&& scalar_;
};
```

`RefTypeSelector` has specialization for `Value_wrapper`:

```
template<> struct RefTypeSelector<Value_wrapper> {
    using Type = Scalar;
};
```

The binary operator definition remains the same:

```
template<class Left, class Right>
ScalarBinaryOp<Left, Right> operator+(const Base<Left>& left, const Base<Right>& right) {
    return {static_cast<const Left&>(left), static_cast<const Right&>(right)};
}
```

Complete example: https://godbolt.org/z/sJ3NfG

(I used some C++17 features above only to simplify the notation.)

Comment: Thanks. This answers the 2nd part of my question. But I still need to write 4 methods for every binary ops and 2 for every unary ops. Is this possible to write a single template method for every operator? The Value_wrapper is however not interesting because of the syntax and also the user does not in general know if f(y) returns an unevaluated expression on scalar or a scalar.

Comment: @BernardGODARD, you either write 4 methods or use forwarding references with SFINAE that checks if `Left` and `Right` are convertible to `Base<Expr>` for some `Expr`. I don't see other alternatives here. `Value_wrapper` can work with expressions, too. Its role is just to pass information about how to store an argument inside the expression.

Comment: Thank you. I will try SFINAE then.

Comment: @BernardGODARD, after you implement SFINAE and see how it works in practice, please leave a small note here about whether this approach turned out to be a feasible one. This is an interesting problem. Be careful: if the storage type is inferred from the value category only, some innocently looking code like `auto s = x + y; return s + ...;` will result in a dangling reference to the local variable `s`.

Comment: The case you describe is only a problem for methods returning Expression Template object. The return type of most methods is usually not expression templates but evaluated object (eg Scalar). For methods returning expression templates, the writer is responsible to make sure that no reference to locals are in the expression tree.

Comment: I have finally implemented it. I will add the solution to the original post.